# How did Spider-Man do it?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In the end of Avengers: Infinity War,

> Half the population cease to exist, by kind of disintegrating into nothingness.

For everyone, the above happens pretty fast, however Spider-Man appears to be able to fight/resist it much longer than anyone else, including people "stronger" than him.

How could he do that? Is this power explained somewhere?

Comment: see discussion/answer on sci-fi.se here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187170/why-was-spider-man-the-only-person-to-feel-any-physical-sensation-from-this-even

Comment: I'm not sure there's that clear a distinction between the reaction times. People were disintegrating at very different times and many of them were clearly noticing it while it happened. I would agree it seemed more dragged with Spiderman than anyone else, but I'd ascribe that beyond all to artisitic license for the purpose of emotional impact than a genuine superpower. Though, even if that's the rather clear answer to it, that still makes it an interesting question with potential for looking into Tony's and Peter's characters.

Comment: 1) His spidey sense,
2) To give an emotional context to the scene. Remember, Stark told Peter to go back to Earth but he stayed. And since Homecoming, it is shown that Stark cares of Peter and sees him as a responsibilty.
PS - This scene was one of the most emotional scenes from the movie to people.

Comment: @AnkitSharma, I'm not sure I understand your edit to the question. It was asking why he took the longest, from what I read in the initial post. "How did he know" reads a lot more like poor research effort

Comment: @Gnemlock looks like Spider-Man is the correct name, all sources I found when searching now are pointing to that. :) (reason being that spiderman is too similar to superman, so they wanted to distinguish it.)

Comment: @Gnemlock oh, I assume to make the question fit the accepted answer better. He can give better answer though. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I edited to make question title more meaningful, anyways reverted back as I don't want to change OP's intention

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, remember that it was never planned and most of it was improvised. From [screenrant](https://screenrant.com/avengers-infinity-war-spider-man-death-scene/):

> Appearing at a high school in Iowa, Joe Russo revealed some cool new information from the latest Marvel offering. While he won’t share any spoilers for Infinity War and any future MCU films, he shared that Holland’s heartbreaking plea to Tony Stark was improvised. Courtesy of Reddit user [Anewthrowaway_quest](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/8g10pg/joe_russo_came_and_had_a_qa_at_our_high_school/), the filmmaker shared he just instructed the young actor to act like he doesn’t want to leave, it was Holland who decided to ad-lib his lines: “Mr. Stark, I don’t feel good” and the now iconic “I don’t want to go” phrase. It’s unclear if RDJ’s dialog telling Peter he’s fine was also unplanned, but considering the veteran’s knack for improvisation, it’s not impossible.

So it does become little more stretched than other deaths but also remember he does have a sixth sense called "Spider-sense". So we can presume due to it he felt that something is coming and he did see that people are disappearing so he knows what can happen to him.

Even remember his premonition is not fully consistent in comics either, even one of his clone had it so strong that he could even see future:

> Kaine’s Spider-Sense is more powerful. He can actually see the future, not just get an idea something is about to happen in the next moment. He can’t control his power and choose what to see. Rather, he gets visions of events to come. For instance, in “The Spectacular Spider-Man” #222, by Tom DeFalco and Sal Buscema, Kaine is in the middle of sorting clones from the true Peter Parker when he gets a vision of Mary Jane’s death in the future.- [cbr](https://www.cbr.com/15-powers-you-never-knew-spider-man-had/)

So maybe MCU Spider-Man's premonition/spider-sense is strong enough that he can sense that his reality is getting altered. He was able to sense alien ships from far, so maybe he can sense reality-altering events too.

This is what Weta VFX’s lead supervisor, Mat Aiken [say about it](https://www.quirkybyte.com/blog/2018/05/infinity-war-spider-man-died-last-movie/):

> “Spidey’s really fighting it. He definitely doesn’t want to go and he’s fighting… he’s incredibly powerful, so he’s able to withhold it for a lot longer than some of the others, but in the end he can’t withstand it.”

Comment: Thanks! Never even considered this was improvised, this indeed explains the difference from other cases.